# Interactuar con objetos con z-index inferior

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un elemento CANVAS que ocupa 100% de ancho y alto con z-index 9,
Por debajo tengo otros objetos, un h1, una imagen, podría ir cargando mas, todos con Z-index inferior.

**Lo que quisiera es que el elemento CANVAS se siga viendo por encima de los demás, **pero que la interacción sea con los objetos inferiores**, como si el CANVAS no existiera.**

Me sirven respuestas en CSS, javscript, jQuery. Gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene unos cuantos problemas, lo que tu quieres no es anular el hover del canvas, lo que quieres es poder interactuar con los elementos que están debajo del canvas, dependiendo de que interacción quieres hacer la respuesta puede ser diferente. En el sitio que muestras pues *no* "se ve mejor" el problema, no ayuda en nada. Además no agregaste nada de lo que haz intentado. Los dos últimos problemas que mencioné hacen que las personas voten la pregunta de forma negativa, te sugiero edites tu pregunta para poder ayudar de mejor manera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por las recomendaciones! Encontré una respuesta al problema en esta nota

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083061/make-element-unclickable-click-things-behind-it

La respueta era en CSS: `pointer-events: none`  al elemento que quiero "desactivar"